# Dojo ContentPane | programmatic click

Tags: javascript, dojo

I've created Dojo `ContentPanes` as menu. After connecting the click event to a specific menu item it will open after a click(`on(registry.byId("lalalal"), function()...)`. Now I want to be able to fire a click event programmatically. If I use a `dijit/form/Button` it's no problem, but when I use a `ContentPane` it doesn't seems to work.

I have created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c3xGL/) to show the problem.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Do you want to fire a click event, or call the function attached to the click event? The latter is _much_ simpler. See: http://jsfiddle.net/c3xGL/1/

Comment: Maybe I didn't provide enough background information. I already had a menu(`AccordionContainer` containing `ContentPanes`) and when I click a menu item it will open a new tab in my `TabContainer`. In the recently opened tab I use a grid. When you open the contextmenu on the grid there must be an option to open another tab. These 'tabs' and actions are in fact all working so I my code I wanted to programmatically call the 'onclick' on the menuitem so it will open the desired tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named your modules really confusing... but the onClick event handler is directly bound to the DOM node behind the `dijit/layout/ContentPane` widget.

This means that if you use the following:

```
on.emit(registry.byId("example").domNode, "click", {});
```

It will work.

I updated your fiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/c3xGL/3/

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for, many thanks. You mean 'dom' has to be 'registry'? Normally I use the name 'registry', but in my jsFiddle example I changed the code alot and I forgot to change it back before posting on SO.

Comment: Yeah I meant that :p I was confused at first at what was happening there :p

Comment: I get that. I have to confess it actually IS confusing hehe.